# Is there a way to write two "in" statements in one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

Is there a short version of

```
n = [5, 3, 17]
if 5 in n and 17 in n:
    print("YES")
```

something like that doesn't seem to work

```
if (5 and 17) in n:
   print("YES")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like this instead:

```
n = [5,3,7]

if all(item in n for item in [5,7]):
    print("YES")
```

Answer (score 10):

I don't think there is something exactly like that in Python. The closest I can think of is, `set` operations, eg. `set.issubset`:

```
>>> n = [5, 3, 17]
>>> ({5, 17}).issubset(n)
True
```

Comment: I was about to upvote your other answer for the nice approach (and also comment that it is much less efficient :p), so get a +1 here ;)

Comment: @mozway thanks! I realized that after writing it, and seeing your answer. So upvoted yours and deleted mine. Although I didn't test mine for really large df, not sure if it would change much.

Comment: for 10k items in the dictionary there was a factor ~500 (19ms vs 10s) ;)

Comment: @mozway glad I deleted that snail xD Thanks for the benchmarks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
n = [5, 3, 17]
if set(n) & set((5, 7)):  # Using & which is intersect operator for two sets
    print("YES")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
n = [5,3,17]
search = [5,17]

found = [x for x in search if x in n]
print("Count", len(found))
print("Matched", found)
```